# .isin() function is returning an empty set when filtering an object column in DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, isin

Reading and appending excel files to create DataFrame:

```py
import pandas as pd
import os

folder = r'C:\mypathtodocuments'
files = os.listdir(folder)

df = pd.DataFrame()

for file in files:
    if file.endswith('.xlsx'):
        df = df.append(pd.read_excel(os.path.join(folder,file)))

#Drop extra columns from wrong data
df1 = df[['FIRST_NM', 'LAST_NM', 'CITY_AD']]
```

Preview of `CITY_AD` column:

```
>>> df1["CITY_AD"]

0      EL PASO
1      HOUSTON
2      HOUSTON
3      CONROE
4      MCKINNEY
5      MCKINNEY
6      KATY
7      TOMBALL
8      TOMBALL
9      SPRING
10     SPRING
```

Filter DataFrame with `.isin()` function to only include cities `HOUSTON` and `CONROE`:

```
df1[df1["CITY_AD"].isin(["HOUSTON","CONROE"])]
```

This returns an empty set... How can I get it to filter correctly?

Comment: Provide a reproducible example that contains the original dataframe.

Comment: Given that this is from an excel file is it possible you have extra nonprintable characters in the column? Could that be `" HOUSTON"` or `"HOUSTON "`, for example? The output from `print(df1.head().to_dict())` would really help.

Comment: Try adding this line before the `isin` line: `df1["CITY_AD"] = df1["CITY_AD"].str.strip()` @Joe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```py
df1["CITY_AD"] = df1["CITY_AD"].str.strip()
df1[df1["CITY_AD"].isin(["HOUSTON","CONROE"])]
```

Comment: Yes, using str.strip() fixed the issue! thank you!